# How can I get a 4.26µm wavelength light source with variable intensity?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, infrared-radiation

I want to conduct a small home experiment involving ${\rm CO}_{2}$ particle detection. In order to do that I need a light source at $4.26$ $\mu$m wavelength (it's absorbed by ${\rm CO}_{2}$ molecules), preferably with configurable light intensity.

I checked various stores for LED sources and bandpass filters, but options that I found are too expensive for me ($>\$300$). Is there a cheaper way I can get this?

Makeshift options are also considered. I don't want to use NDIR sensor.

Comment: Just use an incandescent bulb. It produces lots of radiation at all wavelengths. You just need a camera that's sensitive to 4.6 microns.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake it's not okay because there're other gases in the air with different absorption spectrum. It would've been a good solution if I had an access to cheap bandpass filter though

Comment: Easy way to do a differential measurement: fill an otherwise transparent container with 100% CO2, and compare the difference between a container with normal air and the container with CO2.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake interesting approach, but it involves additional instruments (something to achieve pure 100% CO2 at home) and still not quite what I need

Comment: "something to achieve pure 100% CO2 at home" That's easy. Dry ice.